# SendEmailAsync with Attchment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like some help applying IEmailSender Interface to a class of mine called EmailSender.

This interface apply one method called SendEmailAsync(String email, String subject, String message)  which works perfectly!

In some cases i want to send emails with attachments of type base64 string ,using the same way or something similar is it possible or is there a way i didn't think of to manipulate the class?

EmailSender.cs

```
public class EmailSender: IEmailSender
    {
        public EmailOptions Options { get; set; }

        public EmailSender(IOptions<EmailOptions> emailOptions)
        {
            Options = emailOptions.Value;
        }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }

        private Task Execute(string sendGridKey, string subject, string message, string email)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(sendGridKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("no-reply@---", "no-reply"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));
            try
            {
                return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} First exception caught.", ex);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When called:

```
 await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                                   _db.Users.Where("aa@aa.com"
                                    "email subject",
                                    "blah" + blah ");
```

Comment: You want to add email sending with attachment without modifying this class?

Comment: The [SendGridMessage class](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs) contains the AddAttachment() method, you could use it to add attachment in the email message. Please refer to the following links: [Send Email Using SendGrid Email Service with an Attachment](https://medium.com/@shahedbd/send-email-using-sendgrid-email-service-with-an-attachment-aa7046cc0a35) and [How to: Add an attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#how-to-add-an-attachment)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i'd like to modify it if there is a possible way where it will not affect the procedure of "sending emails with no attachments"

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to edit files, the better approach would be to **overload** your method that takes in additional optional parameter of `attachment` or `attachments`. Have this in interface, and properly implement it in your `EmailSender` class.

Since you are using `SendGrid`, here's a link I found to examples - [sendgrid-use-cases-attachments](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#attachments)

A not so preferable way might be to send your attachment in **base64 encoded string be made a part of your message**. Add that, and some other information if needed like length, filename, type, etc. Now, you didn't change any source code, but you have other things to worry about -

- What maximum size attachments might be allowed this way? I imagine there is some **message length limit**.
- **How will you access** the attachment on the client side? It will be just a string that you need to somehow read, decode, and present as the original intended file.
- Will the email go through as normal or get marked as **spam** along the way?

Edit - Potential example for the first one.

```
// Add this method in EmailSender
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message, string attachment=null)
{
    return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email, attachment);
}

// Modify this method if it's not part of any interface
private Task Execute(object sendGridKey, string subject, string message, string email, string attachment=null)
{
    // Add the following after the line "msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));"
    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment)) && File.Exists(attachment))
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(attachment);
        var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        msg.AddAttachment(Path.GetFileName(attachment), file);
    }
 }
```

Remember, I can't test it. Also, I am not comfortable with your code having Tasks, but they are not async, why EmailOptions has public set, etc. But if your code works, and my modifications also work, then you should be able to say -

- `await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email, subject, message);`
- `await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email, subject, message, filepath);` where `filepath` would be a string like `"D:/MyFiles/somefile.txt"`

Comment: Your answers looks promising and i'm intrigued to try both ways. i'd appreciate you if you provide any tried demo especially for the first one... Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, I'am afraid I won't be able to help without significant redesign, because if I understand, you don't wish to make many changes. Also, I don't want to put code when I am not familiar with your codebase, and I don't have sendgrid account yet to test things myself. You say your stuff works, and just need attachment addition. If you were able to do that much already, then you should be able to add attachment feature too in any way you like. I have put link to use case examples for attachments. @ZhiLv also gave links to articles showing how to add attachments.

Comment: @Amani I've still tried to put an example that you might wanna try. Hope it helps, that's the best I can do for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot your time and effort, your answers and comments are highly appreciated :) i'll look into the provided articles.